# How to erase image single finger touch and rotate undo redo?

Tags: android, image, undo, erase, redo

Erase image with single finger touch to rotate and drag and drop image.

`Stickerview` add image and edit with erase

Comment: what you tried so far??

Comment: i tried to implement in with undo and redo.